# Prevent windows 10 from locking with usb stick

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

Quick clarification of the problem:

I work in company and our pc's are managed by administrator.
What do i need is to prevent windows from locking.
I can not run exe files, open registry or other thinks.

I am thinking if this is possible with usb stick. I mean if it is possilbe to send small el. impuls to pc every 2 - 3 mins to prevent from locking. Or make autorun usb stick.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You need to ask your Company IT Admin to help you with this (if they are willing to help with ideas like this).

Comment: Usually there is a reason why the pc auto locks. For example, many companies are ISO certified for a specific certification, and in order for those certifications to be valid, pc's need to be secured, for example, the computer must go on lock if the user is not behind the computer. By creating something that circumvents this setting is similar as to disabling it, which would break ISO. Instead, contact your administrators and ask if they can use Windows Hello to keep your computer unlocked. For example, if your phone is in range, it does not lock, etc...

Comment: "You need to ask your Company IT Admin to help you with this (if they are willing to help with ideas like this)".  My boss in our department must monitor the parameters on 10 monitors at same time. If a problem occurs (that always occurs) his pc lock down. He asked Company IT Admin to prevent there pc to locking and they said no. So they did this trick with usb stick but i dot know how.

Comment: Ask your boss how they did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I am thinking if this is possible with usb stick**

You can program a small USB-stick Arduino to act as a USB-keyboard that presses some innocuous key every few seconds - maybe program it to press some unused key such as Scroll-lock briefly on and off every 30 seconds.

[image: Digispark]
<sup>About $2 on eBay</sup>

The code in the Arduino IDE would be something like

```
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"
#define KEY_SCROLL_LOCK 71

void loop() {
    DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_SCROLL_LOCK);
    delay(30000);
}
```

Or you could use a more expensive ATmega32u4 based Arduino and use the standard Keyboard library rather than Digistump's

[image: Beetle]
<sup>A "Beetle" ATmega32u4 based *Arduino Leonardo* clone that can act as a plug-in USB keyboard emulator</sup>

---

The *right* thing to do is to talk to your manager and to your IT department - their job is to support your business objectives.